# Socket connection refused by Apache2

Tags: apache, socket.io, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I recently transitioned from CentOS to Debian 10 and now I cant seem to get Apache's configuration right for my websockets on my websites.
My virtual host looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxxxxx.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dc
ErrorLog /var/www/html/dc/error80.log

ProxyRequests on
ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33030/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33030/ retry=0
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName xxxxx.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dc
ErrorLog /var/www/html/dc/error443.log

SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/html/dc/dc.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/html/dc/dc.key"

ProxyRequests on
ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33030/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33030/ retry=0
</VirtualHost>
```

My node app is pretty simple impementation of socket.io:

```
io = require('socket.io')()

io.on('connection', socket => {
 console.log(socket.id);
 PlayerController.init(socket);
});
```

My client code:

```
const Socket = io();
 
 Socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(Socket.id);
 });
```

This exact same setup worked on my old server, but not on this ditro's Apache. In the error logs, i get the following:

```
[proxy:error] [pid 16337] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33030 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) failed
[Fri Feb 12 08:55:05.663745 2021] [proxy_http:error] [pid 16337] [client xxx.xx.xx.xxx:45566] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The pages serve fine, it is only my websockets that wont connect. Ive scoured the internet for days now, and have tried multiple combinations of VirtualHost settings, as well as client and server socket.io settings, but to no avail. What am i missing here?

EDIT - Debug logs:

```
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.714297 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 12748] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH01964: Connection to child 16 established (server xxxxxxx.com:443)
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.714949 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12748] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2319): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername xxxxxxx.com found[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.714972 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12748] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2319): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername xxxxxxx.com found[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.714978 2021] [core:debug] [pid 12748] protocol.c(2314): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH03155: select protocol from , choices=h2,http/1.1 for server xxxxxxx.com
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.797865 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12748] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2235): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.3, Cipher: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits)
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.798027 2021] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 12748] mod_socache_shmcb.c(495): AH00831: socache_shmcb_store (0xbe -> subcache 30)
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.798054 2021] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 12748] mod_socache_shmcb.c(849): AH00847: insert happened at idx=1, data=(205:237)
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.798063 2021] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 12748] mod_socache_shmcb.c(854): AH00848: finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=0/2, data_pos/data_used=0/409
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.798070 2021] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 12748] mod_socache_shmcb.c(516): AH00834: leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.798730 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12748] ssl_engine_kernel.c(383): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 16 (server xxxxxxx.com:443), referer: https://xxxxxxx.com/game/
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.798770 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12748] mod_authz_core.c(846): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives), referer: https://xxxxxxx.com/game/
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.798819 2021] [proxy:debug] [pid 12748] mod_proxy.c(1249): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0), referer: https://xxxxxxx.com/game/
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.798838 2021] [proxy:debug] [pid 12748] proxy_util.c(2316): AH00942: HTTP: has acquired connection for (localhost)
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.798890 2021] [proxy:debug] [pid 12748] proxy_util.c(2369): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH00944: connecting http://localhost:33030/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NUpHlmw to localhost:33030, referer: https://xxxxxxx.com/game/
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.798900 2021] [proxy:debug] [pid 12748] proxy_util.c(2578): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH00947: connected /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NUpHlmw to localhost:33030, referer: https://xxxxxxx.com/game/
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.799023 2021] [proxy:debug] [pid 12748] proxy_util.c(2879): AH00951: HTTP: backend socket is disconnected.
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.799105 2021] [proxy:debug] [pid 12748] proxy_util.c(3038): (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to [::1]:33030 (localhost) failed
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.799200 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 12748] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:33030 (localhost) failed
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.799212 2021] [proxy_http:error] [pid 12748] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost, referer: https://xxxxxxx.com/game/
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.799217 2021] [proxy:debug] [pid 12748] proxy_util.c(2331): AH00943: HTTP: has released connection for (localhost)
[Wed Feb 17 22:55:12.799351 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12748] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:39998] AH02001: Connection closed to child 16 with standard shutdown (server xxxxxxx.com:443)
```

Comment: Some firewall, iptables, ... blocking port 3030?  Log no the machine that is supposed to run your app, and make sure port 3030 is open (in LISTEN when doing `netstat -an`), you can try `nc -vz xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 3030` to ensure the port is accessible from the client machine.

Comment: @Nic3500 33030 does show as listening when I run `netstat -an`. I also get a connection via nectat to port 33030. Apache seems to be refusing the request locally.

Comment: If not already done, add `LogLevel debug`, and try again.  You should get more output in your error_log, along with proxy actions.  Otherwise, you should look at logs on the applicaiton that listens on 3030 to see if the connection is seen by the software, and any log that might indicate why the connection is refused.

Comment: Nic3500, see my edit.